# command on specific device

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch script, which will always be executed at a specific location (in this case on my USB-Stick), so typically I would use `D:`, but sometimes the stick has another drive letter. Therefore I am trying to find the device via its name (`USB_Stick`).

I haven't found a way to do this via a batch command.

A PowerShell command would look like this:

```
@(get-wmiobject -query \"select deviceid from win32_logicaldisk where volumename='USB-STICK'\")[0].deviceid"
```

but I don't know how to use the result of this PowerShell command.

I tried things like this:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%x in (`powershell.exe -Command "@(get-wmiobject -query \"select deviceid from win32_logicaldisk where volumename='USB-STICK'\")[0].deviceid"`) do (
    set res=%%x
)
@echo %res%
```

but the result of this would only be `ommands.GetWmiObjectCommand` and not the `D:`.

Comment: Did you mean: looking for the drive letter of your USB drive when connected to any machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going for a batch-script anyway, use the [`wmic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) commandline utility:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%d in (
  'wmic logicaldisk where volumename^="USB-STICK" get deviceid /value'
) do set "deviceId=%%~d"

echo %deviceId%
```

Using the `wmic` with the `/value` parameter creates `name=value` lines as the output, which you can split in the `for` loop by defining `=` as the delimiter.

Comment: I had to add "cd \" so it would definetly go to the root directory but now it seems to work fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the batch file is running on the USB stick? If so, then the drive letter of the stick (without a slash) can be obtained via `%~d0`

Comment: No the batch file can be anywhere therefore i have to find the device via its name (in your case the code would be automatically executed at that point)